# Reward users for clicking on banner ad - swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, admob

My app has recently been updated to show banner ads on a few view controllers. It is a social networking app so users can create posts. I want to create something where users can buy points for a low cost, then posting costs one point. I know how to do this but one thing I want to add is, that a user can click on any of the banner ads to get 2 points, as I still get paid by AdMob and the user can still post. How would I create a function that adds to a users point count when they click on an AdMob banner?

Comment: You want to make user click on ad banner to make you earn more money ?

Comment: At first I wanted to use rewarded video ads which AdMob has an option for but their documentation is very unclear on how to get them working and it seems like those ads are meant more for game apps. So yes, I do want to reward users for clicking on banner ads.

Answer (score 1):

This is consider a clear violation of AdMob Policies. My Recommendation is to avoid this at any cost.

> Publishers may not ask others to click their ads or use deceptive implementation methods to obtain clicks. This includes, but is not limited to, offering monetary compensation to users for viewing ads or performing searches, promising to raise money for third parties for such behavior or placing misleading images next to individual ads.

Alternatively you can use Rewarded Ads or Rewarded Interstitial to do this without any violations, and make sure to follow [AdMob's Policies for ads that offer rewards](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en)

Comment: was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this? @ChristopherMathews